# Infant boarding

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, children

I have bought flight tickets with my wife and our baby 5 months old, but I can not make it to flight.

Will there be any problems if only my wife with an infant will fly without me, the baby is registered on my seat.

Comment: I would assume that it depends on the airline.

Comment: I don't think this would be an issue. I've seen rules such as maximum two infants per one adult, but if you want to be sure you'll have to tell us the airline you are flying with.

Comment: The airline probably doesn't care, but border control might be concerned that one parent is trying to abscond with the child without the consent of the other. You'd have to check the rules in the countries your departing from and flying to. There may be a standard consent form you can use.

Comment: It will be great if you clarify what is your issue. Is it airline (so, we need to check if them). If it is a board country issue... we need to know the about your country and destination....

Answer (score 4):

Call the airline. It's typically not a major problem, but this will be a lot easier if you do some paperwork up front: They should split the reservation into two separate ones, move the baby to your wife's reservation and cancel yours.

This way there is a single reservation for your wife and child that will be flown as booked.